# Interaction Matrix and find cycle

Tags: matrix

So I have a problem in terms of using `FindCycle` because it keeps asking for a graph and I'm unable to convert my matrix into any form of graph from the matrix I complete and I need to keep it a matrix for other functions (adjacency, Kirikhhoff and so forth)

```
n = 5
test = Table[RandomChoice[{-1, 0, 1}], {i, 1, n}, {k, 1, n}]
testgraph = 
 GraphPlot[test, DirectedEdges -> True, VertexLabeling -> True, 
  MultiedgeStyle -> True, SelfLoopStyle -> All]
```

Answer (score 2):

Once you have a legal adjacency matrix, you can convert to a graph object (using `AdjacencyGraph`or `WeightedAdjacencyGraph`) and then apply `FindCycle`. For instance:

```
n = 5; 
test = RandomChoice[{0, 1}, {n, n}]; 
testgraph = GraphPlot[test, DirectedEdges -> True, 
    VertexLabeling -> True, MultiedgeStyle -> True, SelfLoopStyle -> All]
FindCycle[AdjacencyGraph[test]]

{{1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 
  3 \[DirectedEdge] 5, 5 \[DirectedEdge] 1}}
```

Comment: The problem I have is that I need it to be directional and not only undirected interaction matrix.